# Using Webpack with Firebase Messaging service worker

Tags: firebase, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm using Firebase Messaging to send notifications to an Angular web app.  Everything is working, using code like this in my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');

let firebaseConfig = { /* config here */ };
let app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
let messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

I would much prefer not to load the Firebase libraries from the CDN, so I don't have to make sure the library versions match what I'm importing in the web app (via the usual import statements from node_modules).

What seemed to be the right solution is to use Webpack to combine my service worker code above with its Firebase library dependencies, but I can't seem to get it to work.

As an initial test, I used webpack with this code:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';               
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";          
import { onBackgroundMessage } from "firebase/messaging/sw";

let firebaseConfig = { /* config here */ };
let app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  
let messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

I replaced my existing firebase-messaging-sw.js with the webpacked output file, but the browser output shows this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
```

This suggests to me that webpack is including the parts of the Firebase library intended for the browser instead of the service worker.  (I am setting `target` to `webworker` in my webpack.config.js, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.)

How can I accomplish this?  Is it possible with webpack?

Comment: It seems like you're importing `getMessaging` from `firebase/messaging` insteadof `firebase/messaging/sw`

Comment: That was the problem. I was copying it from the sample code in the Firebase documentation, which was wrong. (Post this as an answer instead of a comment and I can award you the bounty I think!)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation error. I will get that fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to the fact that you're importing `getMessaging` from `firebase/messaging`:

```js
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";
```

To use Firebase in a service worker you should import it from `firebase/messaging/sw` instead:

```js
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging/sw";
```